# GRE tunnel to home network

Tags: tunnel

I'm trying to setup a GRE tunnel from a VPS from Hetzner to my home server. My home server is exposed via DMZ through an Asus RT-AC68U router. I'm using this tutorial: https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/linux-setup-gre-tunnel

I'm stuck at the ping part: my home server can't ping to 10.0.0.1 and my VPS can't ping to 10.0.0.2.

Is this even possible? If so, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Some routers block GRE. Also, GRE is not encrypted. Any particular reason you have to use GRE, and cannot use some other kind of VPN (OpenVPN, tinc, WireGuard)?

Comment: @dirkt I just found GRE to be easier (for other things). I am using it as a Minecraft server with web panel. So I need ports. Is this also possible with a VPN?

Comment: Mostly anything you can do with GRE you can also do with WG or OpenVPN. Most VPNs are still just IP tunnels (or even Ethernet tunnels) – people just usually say "VPN" when it's encrypted and/or has authentication, multi-client routing, etc. and "tunnel" when it's not.

Comment: Yes, any kind of VPN will allow port numbers. Most VPNs will also allow connecting two subnets with many IP addresses in each (though in some it's more difficult to set up correctly, like OpenVPN).